# jQuery append different text each click

Tags: jquery, click, append

I have a basic jQuery function going on:

```
$("#selector").click(function(){
    $("#target").append("Some text to be added...");
});
```

That works fine, except I want to append different text on each sequential click. For example:

1. First click appends text "Message 1"
2. Second click appends text "Message 2"
3. Third click appends text "Message 3"

and so on and so forth...

Also, I would like to set a limit, to say, 4 which after 4 clicks, nothing else happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var messages = [
  'First click appends text "Message 1"',
  'Second click appends text "Message 2"',
  'Third click appends text "Message 3"'
];

var i = -1;

var target = $("#target");

$("#selector").click(function(){
    target.append(messages[i = ++i % messages.length]);
});
```

This will actually "append" them. If you wanted to replace each message each time, you'd use `.text()` instead of `.append()`.

***DEMO** (using `.text()`):* http://jsfiddle.net/thVK6/

The `i` variable will be incremented with each click. When `i` is equal to `messages.length`, it will be reset to `0`.

So with each click, `i` is used to grab a new message from the Array.

---

To further explain the increment trick, the `%` modulo operator returns the remainder when dividing `i` by `messages.length`.

When `i` is equal to `messages.length`, the remainder is `0`, so we're back to the start.

```
var i = -1;
```

*First click:*

```
++i; // 0
i = i % messages.length; // 0

messages[ i ]; // first message (index 0)
```

*Second click:*

```
++i; // 1
i = i % messages.length; // 1

messages[ i ]; // second message (index 1)
```

*Third click:*

```
++i; // 2
i = i % messages.length; // 2

messages[ i ]; // third message (index 2)
```

*Fourth click:*

```
++i; // 3
i = i % messages.length; // 0, because 3 % 3 === 0

messages[ i ]; // first message (index 0)
```

...and so `i` is now `0` again, so it starts over.

---

So the same increment trick, but spelled out as above would be...

```
$("#selector").click(function(){
    ++i;
    i = i % messages.length;

    target.append(messages[ i ]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thVK6/4/

Comment: Could you please explain this syntax a little more?

messages[i = ++i % messages.length] ... I'm unfamiliar. Thanks!

Comment: @j-man86: Yep, already updated. I'll give another update to explain more.

Comment: `messages[i = ++i % messages.length]` - I think this is a bad idea. Code should not be confusing. You don't want to return to this code in a few weeks and wonder what you did there. I recommend multiple statements instead.

Comment: So i know messages[i] refers to the index of the array, but what about "++i % messages.length"? I'm just not familiar with the "%". And is ++i the same as i++?

Comment: @j-man86: I updated with more info. And `++i` is a pre-incrementing operator. It ensures that `i` is incremented *before* being evaluated into the rest of the expression.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: IMO, this code isn't confusing once you know what it does.

Comment: @amnotiam There are three operations involved here: (1) incrementing the counter variable, (2) checking if array length was reached and resetting the variable if necessary, and (3) retrieving the corresponding message. Squeezing all these into a single statement makes the code unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: If you're accustomed to seeing this technique, you know its meaning immediately. I'm not asking anyone else to like it, use it or vote for my answer. Just throwing it out there as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
(function () {
    var messages, i;

    i = 0;
    messages = [
        'Message 1 ... ',
        'Message 2 ... ',
        'Message 3 ... '
    ];

    $( elem ).click( function () {
        if ( i === messages.length ) { i = 0; }
        $( target ).append( messages[ i ] );
        i += 1;
    });
}());
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/RhBAh/

Answer (score 0):

reference: http://jsfiddle.net/HDUAK/2/

```
<div id="selector">Select</div>
<div id="target">Target</div>


var i = 1;
$("#selector").click(function(){
    if(i > 4) {return false} else {
         $("#target").append("Message"+i);
    }

    i++;
});
```