# How to detect that the last or 1st list item is displayed in its container with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I'm doing a carousel for the 1st time and I'm having difficulties to detect when the last or 1st `<li>` in the list is displayed in the viewport (its container). I want that when the last item is displayed to either disable the next or previous buttons, or to continue from the 1st or vice-versa (I haven't decided yet on what should happen...). And no plugins please, I'm still in my learning phase...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aayPV/

```
var slidesList = $('#slides').find('ul'),
    slide = $('#slides li');

slidesList.css('width', (slide.length * slide.outerWidth(true)));

$('#ctrls').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
  var thisElem = $(this),
      lastLiPos = slidesList.find('li:last').position(),
      lastLiPosLeft = lastLiPos.left,
      lastLiPosTop = lastLiPos.top;

  e.preventDefault();

  if (thisElem.hasClass('next')) {
    slidesList.animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + slide.outerWidth(true) + 'px' }, 300);
    if ($('#slides li:last').position().left < ((slide.length * slide.outerWidth(true)) - (slide.outerWidth(true) * 5))) {
        //Disable nextbutton
    }
  } else if (thisElem.hasClass('prev')) {
    slidesList.animate({ marginLeft: '+=' + slide.outerWidth(true) + 'px' }, 300);

    //If 1st item is displayed, disable prev button
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel">
  <div id="ctrls">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>

  <div id="slides">
     <ul>
       <li><p>1</p></li>
       <li><p>2</p></li>
       <li><p>3</p></li>
       <li><p>4</p></li>
       <li><p>5</p></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ctrls {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#slides {
    width: 305px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slides li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    float: left;
    color: #777;
}
#slides li p {
    font-family: arial, tahoma;
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the index of the li elements. Get the length of the ul by using $('.slides ul').length. Based on that length you can then determine if the index of the list item - $('.slides ul li').index() is in the viewport, using the left position of the list item, as you already have done in your code. You can calculate the position of the li relative to the ul. You can read more about index here - http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: @Sagar Patil: thanks for your suggestion but because I'm kinda new with JS, can you show some example in a jsfiddle link, please? I get what you're saying half way through but not till the end, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NEW UPDATED ANSWER***

I've updated your fiddle...
for reference http://jsfiddle.net/aayPV/22/

I think checking on the value of a single variable will be alot more efficient than checking the position of the slide against the length of the total slider...

```
var slidesList = $('#slides').find('ul'),
    slide = $('#slides li');

slidesList.css('width', (slide.length * slide.outerWidth(true)));

var i=0,
    last = slide.length - 3;

$('#ctrls').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
    var thisElem = $(this),
        lastLiPos = slidesList.find('li:last').position(),
        lastLiPosLeft = lastLiPos.left,
        lastLiPosTop = lastLiPos.top;


    console.log(lastLiPosLeft, '\n', slidesList.position().left);

    e.preventDefault();

    if (thisElem.hasClass('next')) {
        if(i==last) {
             alert('end'); return false;
        } else {
            ++i;
            slidesList.animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + slide.outerWidth(true) + 'px' }, 300);
        }
    } else {
        if (thisElem.hasClass('prev')) {
            if(i==0) {
                 alert('beginning'); return false;
            } else {
                --i;
                slidesList.animate({ marginLeft: '+=' + slide.outerWidth(true) + 'px' }, 300);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

**OLD ORIGINAL ANSWER**

http://jsfiddle.net/YmjF7/31/

```
var items = $('li');

var i = 0,
    last = items.length -1;

$('#next').click(function(){
    //increment i until it reaches the end of the array
    if(i == last) {alert('end'); return false;} else {
        i++;
        i = i % items.length;
        alert('Item '+ (i+1));
    }
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    //decrease i until it reaches the beginning of the array
    if(i == 0) {alert('beginning'); return false;} else {
        --i;
        i = i % items.length;
        alert('Item '+ (i+1));
    }
});
```

I give some credit to the following questions/answers:

[Increase and decrease a variable until a number is reached in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496576/increase-and-decrease-a-variable-until-a-number-is-reached-in-javascript)

[jQuery append different text each click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918182/jquery-append-different-text-each-click/8918255#8918255)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not doing what I want. Check the jsFiddle in my question. To simplify my question, the carousel has to work as the one in my jsfiddle, i.e. sliding and right and left, but I just need to find a way to know if the 5th `<li>` is in the viewport so that I can disable the next button.

Answer (score 2):

I hope below codes will help you,

```
if (thisElem.hasClass('next')) {
    if(lastLiPosLeft >= 2 )  { //I have edited this line changed >=0 to >=2
    slidesList.animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + slide.outerWidth(true) + 'px' }, 300);

    }
    else  {
        $(".next").css('display', 'none');
    }
} else if (thisElem.hasClass('prev')) {
    //if(  ) //this is for previous button
    slidesList.animate({ marginLeft: '+=' + slide.outerWidth(true) + 'px' }, 300);
```

same condition take for right position and fix for previous button.

I have tested for Next.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but it's not what I want. Check my jsFiddle in the question. To simplify my question, the carousel has to slide and right and left, but I just need to find a way to know if the 5th `<li>` is in the viewport so that I can disable the next button. How do I do that?

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. It works but the issue is the 5th element goes outside the viewport entirely until the viewport becomes empty before it disables the 'next' button. But I want that as soon as we can see the 5th is in the viewport then disable the 'next' button. How can I do that? Sorry for asking many questions...